# Magento 2. Category Search engine optimization returns error

Tags: magento2

I have created many categories in my magento site.I want to remove `.html` in category url suffix...When i make empty the text field in

`Configuration->Catalog->catalog->search engine optimization->Category URL Suffix`

It returns following error

> Something went wrong while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'best-seller-1' for key 'BM_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: UPDATE `bm_url_rewrite` SET `request_path` = ? WHERE (`url_rewrite_id` = 238)

I can't find any solution about this..please anyone help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have saved the `URL` key as **'best-seller'** in

```
'Marketing->Url Rewrite'
```

Delete and remove `'.html'` from the configuration.